# HTML5: resume played video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am creating a "video wall": I am going to show 40+ streams on my HTML5 web page. So, everything goes OK but if one of streamers is stopped to send packets (power/network outages) the page must be refreshed to continue playing the video. I would like to know how to automatically refresh ONLY this specific object and continue showing the video after stream becomes active again? Any ideas?

Comment: Please share some code to understand what you tried

Comment: You are probably looking for either stalled or suspend [media Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)

Comment: Yes,  Kaiido you're right. Can you share some example? Thanks in advance

Comment: something like `vid.onstalled = function() {
    alert("Media data is not available");
};` would get you started, but check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for getting started on SO

Comment: Finally, the solution found!

<script>  
 var vid = document.getElementById("video1"); 
 vid.addEventListener('ended',function(){checkforVideo();},false);
 vid.addEventListener('suspend',function(){checkforVideo();},false);
 vid.addEventListener('stalled',function(){checkforVideo();},false);
</script>

<script>
 function checkforVideo() 
 {
 var vid = document.getElementById("video1");
    var timerId = setInterval(function() 
 {
  if(vid.readyState < 4)
   { 
    vid.load();
    vid.play();
   }
 }, 2000);
}
</script>